# how to populate array of objects from another array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array

```
FruitsList = [
                {name: 'apple', color: 'red'}, 
                {name: 'grapes', color: 'violet'}, 
                {name:'avocado', color: 'green'}
            ]
```

Next I want to fill another array of objects

```
Food = [{fruitName: '', fruitColor:''}]
```

from all the values of the previous array. I tried mapping but failed. Can anyone help what approach in Javascript or Typescript I can use?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
const Food = FruitsList.map(({name, color}) => {
  return { fruitName: name, fruitColor: color };
})

console.log(Food);
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Thank you so much!. My situation now is I have an array object that I reduced to get only those that matched a value I want. Can reduce be also used along with mapping on one function/method?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
food = [];
var list = [
  { name: "apple", color: "red" },
  { name: "grapes", color: "violet" },
  { name: "avocado", color: "green" }
];
list.forEach(function(element) {
  food.push({ fruitName: element.name, fruitColor: element.color });
});
console.log(food);
```

Answer (score -1):

why won't you try this

```js
const FruitsList = [{name: 'apple', color: 'red'}, {name: 'grapes', color: 'violet'}, {name:'avocado', color: 'green'}]

const Food = [...FruitsList , {fruitName: '', fruitColor:''}]
```